# need to load xt_tcpudp module in Debian 7 Wheezy with OpenVZ kernel. Error: 'could not open'

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, openvz, kernel-modules

I followed this guide

[IPTABLES inside container guide @ openvz.org](http://openvz.org/Setting_up_an_iptables_firewall#Setting_up_a_firewall_that_allows_per-container_configuration)

I'm running Debian 7 Wheezy x64 which was dist-updgrade'd before installing OpenVZ. The container is Debian7 x64 minimal.

It's working really well except now I need to have some IPTABLES rules inside one of my containers (VM's).

I tried to load the module **on the host node** like this:

`root@baremetal-openvz-hostnode:~# modprobe xt_tcpudp`

And got this error:

`libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:505 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file: could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/2.6.32-openvz-042stab093.5-amd64/modules.builtin.bin'`

`FATAL: Module xt_tcpudp not found.`

`root@baremetal-openvz-hostnode:~# ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/netfilter | grep xt_tcp`

`xt_tcpmss.ko`

The other two modules mentioned in the guide *(linked above)* loaded without issues.

**The reason I need the xt_tcpudp module**

I'm trying to set these IPTABLES rules inside the container:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -o ppp0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A INPUT -i ppp0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

I get these errors (the above mentioned guide says they occur because the kernel module is missing)

`iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

`iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.`

===========

Comment: I hate OpenVZ (the current 2.6.x version, anyway) with a passion, but this is still a reasonable question.

Comment: okay, thanks for moderating. BTW I'm new to OpenVZ and I love it. Maybe it's because I'm using it on a Debian hostnode. I tried to install CentOS 6.5 for hours and it was an epic fail. OpenVZ on Debian has been a breeze, aside from my lack of familiarity with OVZ and various other general things I've needed to setup. I've used KVM before but it can't provide what I need for my current project. Every tool has it's pros and cons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Okay, it turns out that most information that one will find by doing google searches about *using iptables inside OpenVZ VM's* is obsolete**

I solved the issue by doing the following:

**Load *all* IPTABLES modules on the host node** (I may remove some after this)

Inside `/etc/vz/vz.conf`:

`IPTABLES_MODULES="iptable_filter, iptable_mangle, ipt_limit, ipt_multiport, ipt_tos, ipt_TOS, ipt_REJECT, ipt_TCPMSS, ipt_tcpmss, ipt_ttl, ipt_LOG, ipt_length, ip_conntrack, ip_conntrack_ftp, ip_conntrack_irc, ipt_conntrack, ipt_state, ipt_helper, iptable_nat, ip_nat_ftp, ip_nat_irc, ipt_REDIRECT, xt_mac, ipt_recent, ipt_owner"`

(Note that the old parameter `IPTABLES=` is obsolete)

**Restart OpenVZ**

`root@baremetal-openvz-hostnode:~# /etc/init.d/vz restart`

*Enable all of the netfilters (new keyword) on the container:*

`root@baremetal-openvz-hostnode:~# vzctl set 1234 --netfilter full --save`

`root@baremetal-openvz-hostnode:~# vzctl restart 1234`

Alrighty.

**Here are the relevant docs:**

1. The [new list of IPTABLES netfilter module names](http://openvz.org/Man/vzctl.8#Netfilter_.28iptables.29_control_parameters).
2. The [new OpenVZ global parameters](http://openvz.org/Man/vz.conf.5#Global_parameters)

Comment: Please note that the [official OpenVZ documentation page](http://openvz.org/Setting_up_an_iptables_firewall#Setting_up_a_firewall_that_allows_per-container_configuration) that I linked in my question is obsolete as well. Firstly it says it's necessary to load the xt_tcpudp kernel module (that was not possible using the latest software) and also it recommends using the `IPTABLES=` global parameter that is also obsolete.